# Retrieve all instances of a regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have this string (example):

```
"St 28828 En, St 217n En, St 38729mdnj dnj]spw En"
```

If I run this code...

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("St(?s)(.*)En");
Matcher matc = patt.matcher(vartext);
boolean found = false;
while (matc.find()) {
    found = true;
    Log.d("LogCalc", matc.group());
} 
if (!found) {
    Log.d("LogCalc", "Nothing");
}
```

I get the entire string, I assume because the very first string starts at `St` & the very last ends at `En`. How can I get each individual iteration: `28828`, `217n`, `38729mdnj dnj]spw`? I assume there is a way to have the regex pattern start from the beginning.

Thanks,

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, with <.*?> I'm able to resolve the string covering from start to end. Can regex do the iteration as well? Or I might need to use replacement options to get them?

Comment: "Can regex do the iteration as well?" I am not sure what you mean since you are already iterating over all matches in your code via `while (matc.find()){ ... matc.group().. }`?

Comment: It resolves partially, as "?" helped with ensuring I don't get the entire string from beginning to end, but only the first iteration. Right now I'm missing to know if regex can repeat the process & retrieve each individual instance by itself, or I need to iterate with a while or so.

Comment: I see. "found = true" was breaking the iteration. Thanks!!!

Comment: "*`found = true` was breaking the iteration*" that shouldn't be happening in your example since loop condition is based only on `matc.find()`. Also there is no `break` nor `return` based on `found`. I am guessing that you ware talking about your *real* code, not the one posted here. Anyway congrats for finding that problem, and good luck with your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... I get the entire string, I assume because the very first string starts at `St` & the very last ends at `En`. ..."*

With *[Matcher#group](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group())*, if no argument is specified, it will return the value of the entire match—not just the *capturing group*.
The problem with the pattern is that it should be using a *[lazy-quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching)*, `?`.

This will match the first encountered `En`, as opposed to the last.

```
St(?s)(.*?)En
```

From here, to return the value of the captured group, provide the number as a value.
Group numbers start at *1*—a *0* will return the entire match, similar to what you currently have.

*[Matcher#group (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))*.

```java
matc.group(1)
```